# Titlesec problem, defining space before section with \titlespacing

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

I am using the `article` document class and have trouble with the `\titlespacing` command of the [`titlesec` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) (explicit).

I want to have more space before the `\section`. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{parskip}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
 {\Huge}{\filleft\thesection}{-2ex}
  {\hspace*{\dimexpr-6em-10pt\relax} 
   \advance\hsize6em\advance\hsize10pt% 
   \rule[0.5ex]{6em}{1pt}\hspace{10pt}% 
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\raggedright#1\end{varwidth}%
   \hspace{10pt}\xrfill[0.5ex]{1pt}%
 } 

\titlespacing{\section}{0cm}{8cm}{2cm}

\begin{document}
\section{abc}
abcbacbabcbabcbacbabcbabcbabcbac
\cleardoublepage
\section{def}
abcbacbabcbabcbacbabcbabcbabcbac
\end{document}
```

But I have trouble with the `\titlespacing` command, it seems like it is getting overwritten by something.
Has it got to do with the explicit command of the titlesec package?

---

Another question:
With my current section heading style, is it possible to only enlarge the section number without enlarging the section text?

Comment: Vertical space at the beginning of pages is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read Enrico's comments above:

> Vertical space at the beginning of pages is removed.

That should answer your first question. Coming to the second question, it is possible. I will show at least two ways.

Method -1:

Load `graphicx` package and use its `scalebox` macro like:

```
    \titleformat{\section}[display]
     {\Huge}{\filleft\scalebox{2}{\thesection}}{-2ex}            %% here
      {\hspace*{\dimexpr-6em-10pt\relax}
       \advance\hsize6em\advance\hsize10pt%
       \rule[0.5ex]{6em}{1pt}\hspace{10pt}%
        \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\raggedright#1\end{varwidth}%
        \hspace{10pt}\xrfill[0.5ex]{1pt}%
    }
```

Method - 2

Use an appropriate scalable font (like `lmodern`) and use `\fontsize{55}{65}\selectfont\thesection`

```
\titleformat{\section}[display]
 {\Huge}{\filleft\fontsize{55}{65}\selectfont\thesection}{-2ex}
  {\hspace*{\dimexpr-6em-10pt\relax}
   \advance\hsize6em\advance\hsize10pt%
   \rule[0.5ex]{6em}{1pt}\hspace{10pt}%
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\raggedright#1\end{varwidth}%
   \hspace{10pt}\xrfill[0.5ex]{1pt}%
 }
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{graphicx}

%\titleformat{\section}[display]
%     {\Huge}{\filleft\scalebox{2}{\thesection}}{-2ex}            %% here
%      {\hspace*{\dimexpr-6em-10pt\relax}
%       \advance\hsize6em\advance\hsize10pt%
%       \rule[0.5ex]{6em}{1pt}\hspace{10pt}%
%        \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\raggedright#1\end{varwidth}%
%        \hspace{10pt}\xrfill[0.5ex]{1pt}%
%    }

\titleformat{\section}[display]
 {\Huge}{\filleft\fontsize{55}{66}\selectfont\thesection}{-2ex}            %% here
  {\hspace*{\dimexpr-6em-10pt\relax}
   \advance\hsize6em\advance\hsize10pt%
   \rule[0.5ex]{6em}{1pt}\hspace{10pt}%
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\raggedright#1\end{varwidth}%
   \hspace{10pt}\xrfill[0.5ex]{1pt}%
 }

\titlespacing{\section}{0cm}{8cm}{2cm}

\begin{document}
\section{abc}
abcbacbabcbabcbacbabcbabcbabcbac
\cleardoublepage
\section{def}
abcbacbabcbabcbacbabcbabcbabcbac
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can hard code the vertical distance:

```
\titleformat{\section}[display]
 {\Huge}{\vspace*{20pt}\filleft\fontsize{55}{66}\selectfont\thesection}{-2ex}            %% here  added \vspace*{20pt}
  {\hspace*{\dimexpr-6em-10pt\relax}
   \advance\hsize6em\advance\hsize10pt%
   \rule[0.5ex]{6em}{1pt}\hspace{10pt}%
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\raggedright#1\end{varwidth}%
   \hspace{10pt}\xrfill[0.5ex]{1pt}%
 }
```

Comment: I think you are trying to mimic `chapter`s. In that case you better use `book/report` class and play with chapter styles.

Comment: Thx for the help with the section style! I did not understand the comment about my first question: "Vertical space at the beginning of pages is removed." Why is it removed and how do i undo it?

Comment: @Mike It is the default behaviour. Can you be more specific? If you want to mimic chapters, it is better to follow my previous comment.

Comment: @Mike See the last edit.

Comment: Thought i had to use the \titlespacing command but this solves my problem! Thx for the help!